# Is it possible to pass select as an expression in order to make projection DbSet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, entity-framework-6

I would like to query a database table. I wonder if I can use projection by passing an expression to DbSet.

Here is my query:

```
 var gameBankResultVM = await (context.GameBanks
                .Where(l => l.referenceId == confirm.referenceId)
                .Select(g => new GameBankConfirmResponseVM()
                {
                    referenceId = g.referenceId,
                    paymentId = null,
                    productCode = g.productCode,
                    quantity = g.quantity,
                    deliveredQuantity = g.quantity,
                    currency = g.currency,
                    version = g.version,
                    signature = g.signature,
                    ApplicationCode = g.ApplicationCode,
                    productDescription = g.productDescription,
                    unitPrice = g.unitPrice,
                    totalPrice = g.totalPrice,
                    totalPayablePrice = g.totalPrice,
                    coupons = g.coupons.Select(c => new GameCouponBankVM()
                    {
                        Pin = c.Pin,
                        Serial = c.Serial,
                        expiryDate = c.expiryDate
                    }).ToList()
                })).ToListAsync();
```

Here is what I want;

```
public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetGamesProjectionAsync(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> select)
        {
            return await dbSet.Where(where).Select(select).ToListAsync();
        }
```

And calling this method based on my query projection:

```
//Query GameBank database
                var gameBankResult =
                    await _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGamesAsync(g =>
                        g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == null, t => ...);
```

Comment: Look at the signature of the `Select` method, you need to pass the right thing in...

Comment: You could pass in a string of the columns (separated by a delimiter like ','), but that won't be the type safe way

Comment: `Expression<Func<TEntity, List<TEntity>>>` ?

Comment: No, more like this one: `Select<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)`. Note that the `Select` method doesn't have to return your entity, it could be a DTO, or `int` or something completely different.

Comment: sorry, this is a bit confusing for me :) Can you please write the whole method? `public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetGamesProjectionAsync(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
        {
            return await dbSet.Where(where).Select(selector).ToListAsync();
        }`

Comment: how can I use both where and select in my method?

Comment: The signature of Select is `Select<TSource,TResult>()` That means that the calling code should know both the source entity and the result entity. So the method may as well tap into a method that simply provides `IQueryable<TSource>` and in its own body apply the Select instead of jumping through hoops to pass it as an argument. I mean, it doesn't improve any encapsulation, so what's the benefit?

Comment: @GertArnold at least it will be a method which is more readable :) Would you mind showing the method structure?

Comment: in order to use the query in my generic repository I need to somehow convert my query.

Answer (score 0):

I just omit the select (projection) portion and implement a method for generic repository as follows:

```
public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetGamesAsync(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return await dbSet.Where(where).ToListAsync();
    }
```

The I call it in my business service layer:

```
//Query GameBank database
            var gameBankResult =
                await _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetGamesAsync(g =>
                    g.productCode == requestDto.productCode && g.referenceId == null);
```

And here is the solution to my problem, I used Automapper in order to make the conversion.

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {

                    cfg.CreateMap<GameBank, GameConfirmResponse>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<GameBankPin, Coupon>();
                });
                var iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
var gameBankConfirmResponse = iMapper.Map<IList<GameBank>, IList<GameConfirmResponse>>(gameBankConfirmResult);
```

Now all I need is to use Unity to tidy up all af there mappings around :) Hope someone help me.

**Definitely I need something like below:**

[grouping to generic method in Repository EF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058377/grouping-to-generic-method-in-repository-ef-c-sharp)